# Read setting in host.json from individual function method

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-functions, appsettings

I am trying to figure out if I can read a value that is in the host.json settings area/file.

In other words, if my host.json file/area contains a setting "functionTimeout", is there a way to read that in my function?  Like:

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["functionTimeout"];`

for instance.  Which of course doesn't work.

I am trying to deploy a custom string setting that is accessible to all functions.  And must be deploy-able. I cannot enter it directly via portal ui.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: We basically can't store custom string in `host.json`, which has fixed format and values for host configuration. How do you deploy your code?

Comment: Try to use localsettings.json during development. Once you publish to Azure Function App, you need to add your custom keys using Manage Application Settings in your Function App.